# How to summon a picture without depending on its location file path?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a picture with VBA code in an Excel workbook without depending on the location of the picture.

This image is supposed to go in an Excel header.  The only way I know of inserting images would be by using the `leftheaderpicture.filename` method:

`ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = "F:\BURN IN\Presentation1.jpg"`

Hopefully someone knows a different method to somehow get the image embedded in the code and summon it without relying on a file path pointing to the location of the picture.  The idea is to eventually use this workbook as a template so portability is key.

Comment: So where does the image come from?  Do you mean to store it somewhere in the workbook? What size is it?

Comment: Tim, correct.  If somehow I could "store" the image in the workbook or vba script.  The image is very is small, 9KB or so.

Comment: Maybe look at this post: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?55713-Store-image-in-VBA or this one https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/143385-excel-vba-picture-in-cell-to-header

Comment: Thanks! actually those solutions approach to the best possibility I thought up to this point in the timeline; that is, to have the image stored in a hidden worksheet and programmatically copy/paste it whenever needed.  Actually a very efficient solution.  I'd say this question is answered at this point.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.